# Difference between IAB version 2 and version 3

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

What are the differences between In-App-Billing version 2 and 3? If you can provide some official link of blog or something too. I can't find it anywhere on the developer site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a changelog for V3 on [blogspot](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2012/12/in-app-billing-version-3.html). May this helps you ;)

- An improved design that makes applications simpler to write, debug and maintain. Integrations that previously required several hundred lines of code can now be implemented in as few as 50.
- More robust architecture resulting in fewer lost transactions.
- Local caching for faster API calls.
- Long-anticipated functionality such as the ability to consume managed purchases and query for product information.

Comment: Reading it, I guess it should have the explanation I was looking for. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

- [Features of the different in-app billing versions](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/versions.html)
- [An overview of in-app billling APIs](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html)

Comment: Ahh, Thanks, just found it out. Might have missed earlier.